# How to get max value in loop

Tags: php, max

ok so im working with this loop and getting information from DB:

```
for($i0 = 0; $i0 < $total0; $i0 ++) {
    $id = $oconecta->retrieve_value($i0, "id_tam_product");
    $price = $oconecta->retrieve_value($i0, "price_tam_product");

    echo $id; // RESULTS: 312, 313, 314
    echo $price; // RESULTS: 180.00, 250.00, 300.00
}
```

i was wondering how can i get the MAX value for that loop:

```
echo $id; //RESULTS: 314 
echo $price; //RESULTS: 300.00
```

Comment: Google how to get max valued from Database or Array

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676768/php-get-highest-value-from-array maybe?

Answer (score 2):

```
$maxID = 0;
$maxPrice = 0;
for($i0=0;$i0<$total0;$i0++)
{
  $id=$oconecta->retrieve_value($i0,"id_tam_product");
  $price=$oconecta->retrieve_value($i0,"price_tam_product");

  $maxID = max($id, $maxID);
  $maxPrice = max($price, $maxPrice);
}

echo "MAX ID: $maxID - Max PRICE: $maxPrice";
```

Use the `max()` function to determine the highest number of a set.

Comment: If $id is an ARRAY, simply use `echo max($id)`. If `$id` is a STRING, use `echo max(explode(",", $id))` maybe...

Comment: yeah but if i `echo $maxPrice = max($price, $maxPrice);` inside the loop it echos the 3 values // RESULTS: 180.00, 250.00, 300.00

Comment: You're in a loop... For each iteration of the loop, you're echoing the value. If it loops 10 times, you'll see 10 different outputs. My original answer will alleviate this (edited to remove the echo inside the loop).

Answer (score 1):

Either you use SQL's MAX() if you can modify your SQL query, or keep the max value in a variable in each loop, and reassign it everytime:

```
$firstLoop = true;
$maxId = 0;
$maxPrice = 0;

for ($i0 = 0; $i0 < $total0; $i0++)
{
    $id = $oconecta->retrieve_value($i0, "id_tam_product");
    $price = $oconecta->retrieve_value($i0, "price_tam_product");

    if ($firstLoop) {
        $firstLoop = false;
        $maxId = $id;
        $maxPrice = $price;
    }
    else {
        $maxId = max($maxId, $id);
        $maxPrice = max($maxPrice, $price);
    }
}
```

(the boolean is here if you have negative values it wouldn't work if $maxPrice and $maxId are initiliazed with 0)

Comment: when i echo $maxPrice = max($maxPrice, $price); the result is: 250.00, 300.00 i only need the highest value

Comment: You have to echo it AFTER the for loop.