# Count how many times a word shows in an array?

Tags: php

I'm using an `array_push` to add to an array, that of which how many times a card is there.

```
$array = array();
foreach($aiarray as $card) {
    $cardss = card($card);
    array_push($array, $cardss);
}

asort($array);
print_r($array);
```

This gives me what I need, but now how do I search the array and for say;

pseudo

```
if (*array contains > 2 of the same word) {
    find out what word;
    does the array contain more than one?;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
if (in_array($word, $array)) { 
  $array_keys = array_flip($array);
  $number_of_words = count(array_keys($array_keys, $word));
  if ($number_of_words > 1) {
    echo "array contains word more than once";
  }
}
```

Functions used: [in_array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php), [array_flip](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php), and [array_keys](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)

Answer (score 1):

[Array Count Values](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) and then [PHP Get Highest Value from Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676768/php-get-highest-value-from-array)

Just do

```
$count = array_count_values($array);
$max_times = max($count);
if ($max_times > 2) {
    $word = array_search($max_times, $count);
    .... whatever you need
}
```