# php array, how can i get key name of max value

Tags: php, arrays, max

i am trying to get key of max value
example :

```
$arr=[
 0=>6,
 5=>12,
 4=>10
];
```

i want to get key which have max value

i am sorry for my english thank you :D

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP Get Highest Value from Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676768/php-get-highest-value-from-array)

Comment: it's answer helpful thank you